# Split object list according to some fields

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to split an object list according to the value of certain fields by grouping them.

For a student object :

```
public class Student {
   private int id;
   private String section;
   private Integer age;
   private String city;
}
```

I had a list of

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList()<>;
list.add(new Student(1,"Biology", 23, "New York"));
list.add(new Student(2,"Mathematics", 22, "Chicago"));
list.add(new Student(3,"Technology", 23, "New York"));
list.add(new Student(4,"Biology", 23, "New York"));
list.add(new Student(5,"Technology", 23, "New York"));
list.add(new Student(6,"Biology", 21, "Chicago"));
```

And I want to split it on lists with the same section/age/city.

Means that in my example I'll have 4 lists : (1 and 4), 2, (3 and 5), 6.

There is any easy way to do it with Streams?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver How do you group by multiple fields? Listed question only does one

Comment: Did you tried implement it (with streams or without) ? Please share your attempt and describe the problems you've faced.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` and create a common key. This returns a Map that needs iterated to get the groups.

```
final Map<String, List<Student>> collect = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(student -> String.format("%s:%d:%s", student.getSection(), student.getAge(), student.getCity())));
int group = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Student>> e : collect.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(++group + ": " + e.getValue());
}
```

---

```
1: [Student{id=1, section='Biology', age=23, city='New York'}, Student{id=4, section='Biology', age=23, city='New York'}]
2: [Student{id=3, section='Technology', age=23, city='New York'}, Student{id=5, section='Technology', age=23, city='New York'}]
3: [Student{id=6, section='Biology', age=21, city='Chicago'}]
4: [Student{id=2, section='Mathematics', age=22, city='Chicago'}]
```